# Excel 2013 - Sumifs - Add all cells in a column

Tags: range, excel-2013, sumifs

I have the following formula in my Excel 2013 spreadsheet:

```
=SUMIFS(Employees!$T$2:$T$1114, Employees!$L$2:$L$1114, $A5, Employees!$J$2:$J$1114, 1, Employees!$Q$2:$Q$1114, "N", Employees!$K$2:$K$1114, C$3)
```

It is summing column T based on certain criteria.  Looking at Employees!$T$2:$T$1114 as an example, I have a header row, so I start at T2.  I then select all the cells in that column. which currently ends at 1114.  The problem is, that number can change.

If I want to remove the hard-coding and just select all the cells that contain data in that column, then sum that data based on this criteria, how would I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the header above T isn't sumable, and/or the header above L isn't a valid criteria, then it won't matter if they are included in the sum_range and criteria_range, respectively. In that case, you can specify entire columns, like Employees!$T:$T, and not worry about where the data starts or ends.

```
=SUMIFS($A:$A, $B:$B, G2)
```

[image: simple sumifs example using entire rows]

If there *is* data above the desired part of T, you could add another criteria to avoid it, for instance, by using an additional (hidden) column with markers.

[image: sumifs with extra criteria to avoid headers]

Comment: I tried that originally and was getting errors, but you made me realize I was only changing the sum variable and not the search criteria, so I was getting some unwanted cells.  Thanks for your help.